# Can autosave be disabled in Metro Exodus on PS4?

Tags: ps4, metro-exodus

Is there a way to disable autosave in Metro Exodus? I’ve looked through all of the game options and didn’t see anything obvious, just thought I’d check in case I missed something.

I was in Caspian, driving toward the quest objective in the lower-right corner of the map, and was just approaching it when I was snatched out of the vehicle by a demon. It carried me for a bit and then dropped me - OVER THE WATER — and as the cutscene of my fall played, the game autosaved. Now I’m stuck in an unplayable moment, where the game loads with me dropping into the water and being trapped there until I die...it doesn’t bring me back to dry land as is normally the case when you fall into the water. d’oh!

This isn’t the first time I’ve been bitten by an unfortunate autosave in this game, and I’ve been very aware of planning my strategy because of it. However, this one was out of my control and occured along with a game glitch, which makes me want to stop playing the game.

Comment: I also got hit with a glitch in the Caspian Sea which meant I had to restart the whole chapter. It's a disgrace that the developer hasn't bothered fixing these issues even today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can research Autosave cannot be disabled in Metro: Exodus.

I don't have any sources from the developer, but discussions [on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/412020/discussions/0/2261313417707702022/) and [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/metro/comments/at1z0k/biggest_flaw_lack_of_multiple_save_slots/) indicate that autosave is a permanent, unfortunate, feature of the game.

Difficult autosaves coupled with the lack of manual saving is a common grievance within this game.